# A particle for place of action for V-2+に行く

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-で, verbs-of-motion

What particle should be used for a place of action (or a place to go?) in case of using V-2+に行く construction? E.g.

> 食堂 ＿ 食べに行きます。

At one hand, 食堂 is a place of action (eating) and で-particle should be used.
At the other hand, it's a place to go, so に-particle should be used.
However, the last case seems a bit strange to me, because a verb 行きます already has an object with に-particle - 食べに.

So what's the correct particle to be used in such cases? Maybe both particles are acceptable? - In this case does a choice of particle carry any meaning?

Comment: https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1989185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

に(へ)～しに行く means "to go to the place in order to ～　( to go to the place for the purpose of ～). For example, レストランに食べに行きます( I got to a restaurant to eat). I think 食堂で食べに行きます is unnatural because we don't say place+で+行く. However you can say 毎日昼飯を大学の食堂で食べます, which means "I eat lunch at a refectory in my university ever day.)".

I think you understood them correctly because you knew で is used for a place of action and に is used for a place to go. It is no problem that a verb 行きます already has an object with に-particle.

Comment: へ-particle is also possible? Is there any difference between using へ and 
 に here?

Comment: Yes. The difference is little. に emphasizes the location and へ emphasizes the direction.